# Mac: Certificate expiration date is not consistent

Tags: macos, certificate

In the `Expires` column of the Keychain Access application I can see the expiration date of certificates. Strangely these dates do not match the actual expiration.
See below for an example. This mismatch is the case for all certificates I have in my keychain.
[image]
But when I double click it I see an expiration date of 30 May 2020.
[image]
I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2.
How do I make the dates match?